# Error when project builds in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created yesterday fresh new project in android studio and when I opened it today it shows some anonymous errors in some files.It has replaced my original code in file and app.gradle file also has changed it contains something like as shown in pictures below:

[image]

All the files which are red underlined have same kind of code don't know where it comes from in these files.
Someone please let me know how to correct it.

**Thanks**

Comment: Please provide the code then only we can help you. Also try Rebuilding, also Invalidate Cache and restart.

Comment: @Gourav ,Its a new project and haven't add any new line of code yet and I have tried rebuilding projects and all but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Then please add the code of the build.gradle files. If something is found suspicious, I will inform

Comment: I have attached picture of my app level build.gradle file that contains some suspicious code that replaced original code.

Comment: eeh, looks like an intellij problem. try deleting your iml file and restart the project and see if that helps